# I can't get info pulled from a database to not display end to end on one line in a dropdown list

Tags: php

I'm a student building a PHP project trying to get product names and their respective prices (from a mysql database table) to display one after the other in a dropdown list. The customer will select one of the items, and check one or both of the check boxes before pressing the place order button, at which point their item selection, order total, and chosen gift option will display in table form on a separate page. I've gotten all of the correct info to display in the dropdown list, as well as getting the check boxes to function properly, but all of the product data is on one line, and end to end. I don't get any errors at all when I load the page. I tried it another way in which I defined multiple instances of the echo statement, which formatted correctly, but only listed the first item in the database table repeatedly. These two different approaches are displayed below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   
   <title>Home</title>
   <link href="novusreset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="novusstyles1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="novusstyles2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="novusflex.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
   <link href="novusnavicon.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="novustables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />  
</head>

<body>
   <header>
     <a href="index.html"><img src="novuslogo.png" alt="Novus LLC." /></a>
      
      <nav class="horizontal">
        <a id="navicon" href="#"><img src="novusnavicon.png" alt="" /></a>
         <ul id="navigation">
               <li><a href="index.html" class="first">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="products.php">Products </a>
        <ul id="productlist">
           <li><a href="products.php">PC Parts</a></li>
           <li><a href="products.php">Peripherals</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.php">Networking</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.php">Drinks</a></li>
           <li><a href="products.php">Apparel</a></li>
           
       </ul>
             
           <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
           <li><a href="account.html">Account</a></li>
           <li><a href="cart.html">Cart</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>
   
   
   <section id="main">
      <article id="overview">
          <form action="ordersummary.php">
  <label for="products">Choose a product:</label>
  <select name="products" id="products">
      <option>
<?php 


include('connection.php'); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    echo $row["prod_name"] . " "  . "$" . $row["prod_price"];
} 
   
} else{
    echo "Ahhh yes, the big empty.";
}
mysqli_close( $conn );
?>
      </option></select>
      <label class="container">Gift Wrapping
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
       </br>
<label class="container">Gift Tag
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
       </br>
       </br>
<input type="submit" value="Place Order">
</form>
</article>
</section>
 <footer>
       &copy;2021-Novus LLC. &#8226; 201 Main St. &#8226; Galena Il
   </footer>
</body>
</html>


This next bit of code is the second attempt which displays things in the correct formatting I want it to, but it only displays the first item in the database table repeatedly:



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   
   <title>Home</title>
   <link href="novusreset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="novusstyles1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="novusstyles2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="novusflex.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
   <link href="novusnavicon.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="novustables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />  
</head>

<body>
   <header>
     <a href="index.html"><img src="novuslogo.png" alt="Novus LLC." /></a>
      
      <nav class="horizontal">
        <a id="navicon" href="#"><img src="novusnavicon.png" alt="" /></a>
         <ul id="navigation">
               <li><a href="index.html" class="first">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="products.php">Products </a>
        <ul id="productlist">
           <li><a href="products.php">PC Parts</a></li>
           <li><a href="products.php">Peripherals</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.php">Networking</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.php">Drinks</a></li>
           <li><a href="products.php">Apparel</a></li>
           
       </ul>
             
           <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
           <li><a href="account.html">Account</a></li>
           <li><a href="cart.html">Cart</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>
   
   
   <section id="main">
      <article id="overview">
<?php 


include('connection.php'); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

?>
          <h2>Choose your product and gift options</h2></br>   <form action="ordersummary.php">
  <label for="products">Choose a product:</label>
  <select name="products" id="products">
    <option><?php echo $row["prod_name"] . " "  . "$" . $row["prod_price"] ?></option>
    <option value="$row["prod_name"]"><?php echo $row["prod_name"] . " "  . "$" . 

$row["prod_price"]  ?></option>
        <option value="$row["prod_name"]"><?php echo $row["prod_name"] . " "  . "$" .                     $row["prod_price"]  ?></option>
        <option value="$row["prod_name"]"><?php echo $row["prod_name"] . " "  . "$" . $row["prod_price"]  ?></option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  
       
<label class="container">Gift Wrapping
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
       </br>
<label class="container">Gift Tagging
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
       
       </br>
       </br>
       
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
       
       
 
</form>
       
       

    
<!--} 
    
    
} else{
    echo "Ahhh yes, the big empty.";
    
}

mysqli_close( $conn );

?>-->
          
          
          
          
      </article>
      
      
   </section>
 
   
 
   <footer>
       &copy;2021-Novus LLC. &#8226; 201 Main St. &#8226; Galena Il
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with that code? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt has this issue:

All the products texts are output in *one* `<option>` element:

```
  <select name="products" id="products">
      <option>
<?php 
include('connection.php'); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    echo $row["prod_name"] . " "  . "$" . $row["prod_price"];
  }  
} else{
  echo "Ahhh yes, the big empty.";
}
mysqli_close( $conn );
?>
      </option></select>
```

I assume you want each product to appear in its own `<option>` element -- which will mean they also appear on separate lines. So remove the `<option>` open and close tag from the static part (outside of the PHP snippet), and *include* them inside the loop, in the `echo` statement:

```
  <select name="products" id="products">
<?php 
include('connection.php'); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    echo "<option>" . $row["prod_name"] . " $" . $row["prod_price"] . "</option>";
  }  
} else{
  echo "<option>Ahhh yes, the big empty.</option>";
}
mysqli_close( $conn );
?>
  </select>
```